# Enable F# interactive window in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-interactive

How do I enable the F# interactive window in VS 2010 SP1, installed on Windows XP?

`Alt+Ctrl+F` doesn't do anything and neither do I see `F# Interactive Window` in the `Other Windows` menu.

I can however launch fsi.exe from a separate command prompt.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you have not chosen the 'F# profile' for VS, then you might have to create a new F# project before this will appear on the menu, I forget?

(As per comments below, something was screwy in the install, but `devenv /setup` fixed it.)

Comment: It's there out of the box if you choose the 'general development settings' template, too.

Comment: I did create a new F# project and its working as expected - verified output via console window. I was keen to run the program via the F# interactive shell integrated in VS 2010 which is not working!

Comment: Right, my question is, after creating an F# project, does the "F# Interactive" command now appear on the VS menu?

Comment: no. it doesnt appear. I posted my initial query after I created my first F# project and failed to see the F# interactive window.

Comment: Hmmm.  Long shot, close all instances of VS, from a vs command prompt, run `devenv.com /setup`, wait for it to complete, and the start VS again.  Fix it?

Comment: Another thing to possibly try is press Ctrl-/ to go to the little command window and do `>View.F#Interactive`.

Comment: @sam You could try View -> Other Windows -> F# interactive, I've sometimes found that works, even when Alt-Ctrl-F doesn't.

Comment: Brian "devenv /setup" has solved the issue. Thanks a bunch; though not sure what caused this failure in the first place.

Comment: Hurray, yes, I dunno either, but glad it's fixed.

Comment: Feel free to award me a green check mark for my tireless effort to brainstorm fixes :)